# How to configure Concurrent testing in Jmeter ?

Tags: jmeter

I need to perform the task to include the following scenerio :
2 different admin edit the same customer profile concurrently 
What shall i be doing to configure this concurrent testing .

I have made **Login** thread Group  where i used **CSV config element** to have different login at same time . But i have kept header manager which extract the authentication token from the last login only and edit customer profile is done through the last logged in admin . How can i make 2 different users to edit the customer profile at the same time i.e concurrently ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

> Variables are local to a thread

So if you have 2 threads (virtual users) each of them will have **its own** authentication token (given you really have 2 admin accounts and use different credentials)

Also be aware that the only way to ensure concurrency in order to have requests occur at exactly the same moment is using [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer). If you don't use the timer - JMeter will be trying to send requests by each thread as fast as it can, it may lead to concurrent requests but you don't have any guarantee, especially when it comes to 2 users only.